# How to use scrollTop prop in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, webkit

Looking in this [site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) I see in the browser compatibility section, it looks like this [image: safari webkit]
What does that mean? What do I have to do to use that property in safari?

If I go `element.scrollTop`, that works just like that?

Comment: Yes, as long as `element` is a valid variable containing a reference to an actual Element

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: @epascarello no because I don't have safari. Just checking for compatibility issues :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Webkit](https://webkit.org/) is the browser engine used by Safari and Chrome, the mentioned item in MDN it's only to clarify that all versions in Safari that use webkit (since like forever) support the property perfectly.

Nothing to worry about, just use it wisely as you would with any other modern browser